# C++ std::pair code understanding

Tags: c++, std

So I am looking through this handout that describes the code for `std::pair`. Below is the code:

```
template <class U, class V>
struct pair {
    U first;
    V second;
    pair(const U& first = U(), const V& second = V()) :
        first(first), second(second) {}
};
template <class U, class Y>
pair<U, V> make_pair(const U& first, const V& second);
```

I am trying to understand this code but I am having problems, specifically at the line pair in the struct. I understand that we store two create two variables first and second according to the respective classes.

In the argument of the pair function, I see that we create a new class `U` and `V` and assign them respectively to `first` and `second`, but I don't clearly understand how the `const U&` works because of the ampersand sign. What's more confusing is the use of a colon after the function declaration which I have never seen before used in c++.

I also don't understand the line below declaring `first(first)` and `second(second)` especially with the brackets. Isn't `first` a type, so how are we able to call a function from `first`?

Comment: [References](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) and [constructor initializer lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor).

Comment: The constructor `pair(const U& first = U(), const V& second = V())` may look a bit dubious, but remember that you can bind temporary objects to `const` references. What this does in effect is initializing by default the members `first` and `second` with the default values (0 for plain old types), in case you do not specify the arguments. `pair` uses pass-by-const reference to avoid copying of large objects.

Comment: No, `first` is not a type, it is a member of type `U`.

Comment: For future reference, when asking multiple questions, ask each one in it's own post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll address this by dividing it into parts.

`U&` means that we are passing a variable of type `U` that will be used by reference - the variable used by the constructor is the same one (same memory address and value) that is given as an argument. By saying `const U& first = U()` we are saying that we promise not to change the `first` passed into the constructor (`const ...`), we want `first` to be taken by reference (`...U&...`), and if we don't provide `first` in the constructor we should use a `U` provided by `U`'s default constructor (`... = U()`). For more information on references, [this page](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/611-references/) should help.

`first(first)` is part of a "constructor initialization list" - the preferred method for initializing class member variables in a constructor. We tell the constructor that we are initializing the member variable of `pair` called `first` (`first(...)`) with the argument `first` provided by the constructor (the `U&` we discussed earlier). For more information on constructor initialization lists, [this page](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/) should help.

Comment: Related: both of these concepts are VERY important! Make sure you learn them thoroughly; your code will be much better for it.